# How to compare complete JSON objects

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai

Is there any way to compare 2 json objects using ChaiJS? I want to compare them deeply till the leaf nodes. However, it is better if the code ignore the order of the siblings within the JSON Object - would only validate structure and value and datatype of values. Any help is appreciated.

I just saw the following code, however not sure what is *equalsRec*

```
expect({ a: 3, b: {c: '2'} }).to.equalRec({ a: 3, b: {c: 2} }) //expecting false
expect({ a: 3, b: {c: '2'} }).to.equalRec({ b: {c: '2'}, a: 3 }) //expecting true
```

Comment: Will it be containing non-primitive objects ? 

If you can JSON.stringify both of them simply do that for both objects and compare strings.

Comment: You can compare the JSON from here: http://www.jsondiff.com/
Hope this will help

Comment: Nope. I can't do that. It would mean that I am going to compare the order of the properties in the 2 objects, which I don't want.

Answer (score 9):

First of all there is [no such thing as "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You have object literals. Then "ignore the order of the siblings" object keys have no order.

To compare two objects you could use [`deep` flag](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep)

```
expect(obj1).to.be.deep.equal(obj2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it.